# Mail followers(OpenERP chatter) does not send email to email client softwares, instead received in INBOX in Odoo messaging

Tags: email, odoo, odoo-8

I had included the openerp chatter in my custom module by inheriting 'mail.thread' and adding add follower widget in XML through the following code.

```
<div class="oe_chatter">
                        <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                        <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread" />
                    </div>
```

While I add any follower, it shows the wizard to add contacts, but in reality, it does not send emails to email client like thunderbird or any other. But it is sent to their Inbox under messaging in Odoo.

Can anyone please clear the confusions.? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have made my comments as below , kindly request you to find it as below it may help in your case

**Regading** :**it does not send emails to email client like thunderbird or any other. But it is sent to their Inbox under messaging in Odoo**.

There can have many reason of "**not send emails to email client**"  :

1. Internet Connection Lost .
2. Missing Email Template.
3. Error in Email Template.
4. [Mail Server Not Configure](http://prnt.sc/as7z3v) .
5. [Email Notification Not Enable For User](http://prnt.sc/as7xv2).

You can try this useful  Link also: [How to configure out going  mail server in ODOO](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-to-set-up-e-mail-messaging-with-odoo-61796)

So just ensure these things(specifically 4 and 5)  at your end ,it may work in your case.

Comment: Prakash Sharma, First of all thank you very very much for the classified answer. I am able to resolve half the problem, but one problem is that I had configured OUTGOING MAIL SERVER, let's say abc@companydomain.com and any user with this email id in the preferences is able to send mail, but not for other users.

Comment: I had read that link How to configure Outgoing mail server in ODOO, i am still trying to get a clearer picture of it now